# Preserve Form Data across UI Router views/states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble creating a multi-step form using UI-Router in Angular.

The issue I'm having is preserving the data inputted into the form fields.

I tried following this tutorial as an example, although its a little different than what I'm doing: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

This is how I have it currently setup:

States:

```
.state('start', {
      url: "/start",
      templateUrl: "partials/start.html",
      controller: 'FormController'
    })
    .state('info', {
      url: "/info",
      templateUrl: "partials/info.html",
      controller: 'FormController'
    })
    .state('personnel', {
      url: "/personnel",
      templateUrl: "partials/personnel.html",
      controller: 'FormController'
    })
});
```

My `FormController` looks like this:

```
angular.module('formApp')
.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};
});
```

Here's the main template for my form:

```
<div class="form-container" ng-controller="FormController">
  <section class="form-container__head">
    <div class="form-container__head__img-block">
      <img id="logo" src="http://url.com" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-container__head__title-block">
      <span class="form-container__head__title-block__title">FORM</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <form class="form-container__form" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div ui-view autoscroll="true"></div>
    <pre>
      {{formData}}
    </pre>
  </form>
  <section class="form-container__footer">
    <label class="form-container__footer__text"></label>
    <label class="form-container__footer__dot">•</label>
    <label class="form-container__footer__text"></label>
    <label class="form-container__footer__dot">•</label>
    <label class="form-container__footer__text">www.site.com</label>
  </section>
</div>
```

And here's a section of the info partial:

```
<fieldset class="form-container__form__fieldset">
  <legend class="form-container__form__fieldset__heading"><h2>Information</h2></legend>
  <section class="form-container__form__fieldset__section">
    <div class="form-container__form__fieldset__section__field">
      <label class="form-container__form__fieldset__section__field__label">Number:</label>
      <input class="form-container__form__fieldset__section__field__input" ng-model="formData.number" type="text" name="number">
    </div>
  </section>
</fieldset>
```

My goal is to save the text someone types into the `number` input field above, and save it for submission a few steps down the line in another state/view.

I'm not understanding why when I type data into the number field, the `formData` expression inside the `<pre>` in my main template is not showing it. If I put the `formData` expression inside the `info` partial where I have `ng-model="formData.number"`, it does show correctly. But then it doesn't show in any of the other states once I leave the `info` state. How can this be fixed?

I know I'm probably missing something basic, so please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all these steps really belong together and are not meant to be reused separately, meaning this is a real multi-step form, you can consider moving all intermediate state into one controller handling the mutli-step process.

For this, you can use the mechanism of nested states that share a parent state (and can share the parent's controller when the children's views are included in the parent template using `ui-view`). So you can manage the state in the parent controller and access the data in all child views. Be aware that it is your responsibility to avoid name clashes.

```
.state('multistep', {
  url: "/wizard",
  templateUrl: "partials/multistep-wrapper.html", // must contain a <ui-view/>
  controller: 'FormController'
})
.state('mutlistep.start', {
  url: "/start",
  templateUrl: "partials/start.html",
})
.state('multistep.info', {
  url: "/info",
  templateUrl: "partials/info.html",
})
```

Do not list the controller in the sub-states as this creates new instances which prevents the ability to reference the parent. The urls generated are then relative to the parent state, so that state `multistep.info` will be available under `wizard/info`.

For details see the sample in the ui-router docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#nested-states--views

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although what I'm doing isn't a real multi-step form, this helped me understand what I need to do for mine to work.

Comment: You could also use separate controllers for your child states. You could then use a service in angular to save form data and retrieve it in other child states. You would inject the service into each child controller.